# How to best avoid having unencrypted information logged by an exit node, if encrypted connection is not an option?

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization

There is a role-playing game I would like to play, but I would like to remain anonymous (more like pseudonymous in this case). I want to keep my IP address hidden from the servers.

The main issue I have, if I do this over Tor, I risk having everything that I do in the game captured and logged by the exit node, since the game can't be played through an encrypted connection, as far as I know. That means every action I do in the game could be logged, I am not comfortable with this.

What is the best option I have here?

Edit: I'm looking for the best thing to do privacy-wise, if I'm going to play the game anyway. I considered some options:

Using Tor unmodified, I will get random exit nodes, at least some of them will log.

Using Tor and limiting my exit nodes to more "trustworthy" exit nodes that are less likely to log. But are there any such nodes, and how will I find them? Would it be a good idea to look for a specific country they're located in, or a specific organization that operates these nodes? And is this even a good idea at all? I thought it would not be that bad because I would be pseudonymous instead of anonymous in the game anyway (character).

The other options I thought of are not preferable.

Comment: If you're running their game on your device, what's stopping them from exposing your IP? You'd have to take extra precautions like using a virtual machine that's forced to use tor.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a 'best option' here the way you describe it.

However - playing it over tor makes sure your real IP stays hidden.
The exit node does not get to know your IP, but as you say - the exit node, and/or VPN provider - can log the traffic itself.

It would be a better if the role-playing game had secure connection enabled.

The same issue is there when you browse the web in just http and not https over tor.

Comment: I agree with your points, but I'm still looking for the best thing to do, privacy-wise, if I'm going to play the game anyway. I will edit my question and elaborate, further help would still be appreciated.